# Mudar qualidade da impressão em C#

Tags: c#, impressão

Eu estou criando um programa em que em certo momento ele precisa imprimir um orçamento...

```
using(PrintDocument print = new PrintDocument())
using(PrintPreviewDialog dialog = new PrintPreviewDialog())
{
    print.PrintPage += Print_PrintPage;
    dialog.Document = print;
    dialog.ShowDialog();
}
```

O problema e que ele sempre imprime em alta qualidade, demorando na impressão e gastando bem mais tinta do que o necessário.

Como faço para diminuir a qualidade da impressão assim como em outros programas? 
[image: Opção do Paint]

Comment: Inclua o seu código ao invés do print e inclua o trecho do comando onde está imprimindo.

Comment: Pelo que pesquisei por cima, esse EventHandler "PrintPage" possui uma propriedade: DefaultPageSettings.PrinterResolution.Kind

Comment: muito obrigado, acabou resolvendo o problema.

Comment: @JoinvilleCar confira se as minhas edições e estão corretas e marque a resposta que resolveu o seu problema.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo obrigado pela correção, é a primeira vês que utilizo o site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente utilizar a propriedade Kind do EventHandler Printpage.

```
using(PrintDocument print = new PrintDocument())
using(PrintPreviewDialog dialog = new PrintPreviewDialog())
{
    print.PrintPage += Print_PrintPage;

    //Declara a qualidade pré-definida para a impressão
    print.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterResolution.Kind = PrinterResolution.Low;

    dialog.Document = print;
    dialog.ShowDialog();
}
```

[fonte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.pagesettings.printerresolution(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @MBertolazo Evite dar a resposta somente com o link da fonte, Baseado nos comentários e confirmação do autor da pergunta eu editei o seu post para apresentar a resposta.

Comment: muito obrigado @LeandroAngelo, Anotado.